# How to handle unhandled exceptions in a C# program

Tags: c#, user-interface, exception

I'm writing a program on C# and I'm just starting on using Exception. I've done Java before but I tried to avoid exception at any cost. I understand now that I can't avoid it any longer. So I need some advice. I have a code like this:

```
try
{
    //...
}
catch
{
    //...
}

//...

try
{
    //...
}
catch
{
    //...
}
```

This is a GUI program. I want to make it so that if an exception is caught, the program will basically stop all operation and but not close the program, so the GUI is still there, users can make changes to the problem found.

BTW: Our lecturer will fail us for multiple returns, so that advice won't do

Comment: `Our lecturer will fail us for multiple returns` - sounds like your lecturer hasn't ever seen real-life production C# code...

Comment: If you are able to do it in Java, I can't imagine it be too hard to do in C#... You haven't even shown us what you've tried

Comment: `I've done Java before` - C# is not java. C# is a decent language.

Comment: @HighCore *yawn*  Try harder

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc pardon me, I don't understand your comment. English is not my first language... =(

Comment: What exactly is wrong with two try catch blocks? What is the question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a handler to catch all unhandled exceptions.  The exact mechanism depends on the UI framework you are using.

For WinForms you can do something like

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new 
    UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

// Windows forms exceptions handler
Application.ThreadException += new 
    ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
```

http://kenneththorman.blogspot.com/2010/10/windows-forms-net-handling-unhandled.html

For WPF you would do something like

```
<Application x:Class="UnhandledExceptionHandler.App"
    DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException">
</Application>

private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, 
                       System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the exception
}
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90866/Unhandled-Exception-Handler-For-WPF-Applications

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I noticed that too.  In the distant past when I worked in WinForms, I only set the two handlers and did not use a "safe main" construct like in the article.  I guess that is intended to handle issues while setting up the exception handling.  Personally I never encountered a situation where that would be necessary but I have not encountered every situation.  Note that just the try/catch in main is not in itself sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case Eric J.'s answer is too involved:

I assume since your prof will only permit one return statement that you will have something like a service that does some work and notifies the caller of the status and possibly an error message.

If you can get by with boolean messages, then the following should work for you:

```
public class Service
{
  public bool DoWork()
  {
    bool success = false;

    try
    {
      //code to do work
      success = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      //do something with the ex
      success = false;
    }

    return success;
    }
}
```

Comment: oooh no. never ever do that. Exceptions are exceptions and errors are errors.

Comment: @jgauffin huh? Be a little more specific perhaps? Since programs throw exceptions and not errors, it's not clear what you are implying...

Comment: You are retreating ALL exceptions as an error since you catch it and return a result boolean instead. Never convert exceptions into state flags unless it's clearly been specified that that should be done. In any case there is not a single use case where it's OK to convert `Exception` (instead of a specific one) into a state flag.

Comment: This example is simplified to the extreme and so does not include specific exceptions. Also, the commented 'do something with the ex' portion is meant to indicate the exception should be handled appropriately, such as logging. Also, pay attention to the OP's request: 'I want to make it so that if an exception is caught, the program will basically stop all operation and but not close the program'. But thanks for your input in any case.

Comment: In that case you should show that the code who calls the service class will catch the exception or change so that the Service class doesn't have a return value. The current code do show a bad practice.

Comment: So you don't return messages to your clients? There is a clear Request/Response pattern outlined in many books, including ASP.NET Design Patterns, in which services handle exceptions and return Response objects with Success and Message properties to the client, who is only concerned with the Response, not catching errors. So, unless you give some concrete evidence for why notifying a client of the success of the operation is a bad practice I have to disagree with you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54061/discussion-between-field-b-and-jgauffin).